# Usage and meaning of &^ and &^= operators in Go

Tags: go, operators, token

I've been looking around for about a week now and can't seem to find a decent explanation for these two operators, `&^` and `&^=`, in the Go language and how they are used. Would anybody be as kind as to enlighten me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is easier to understand when we take a look at all the bitwise operators:

```
&    bitwise AND
|    bitwise OR
^    bitwise XOR
&^   bit clear (AND NOT)
```

1. Bitwise AND (`&`): Result is 1 when both operand bits are 1, else the result is 0.
2. Bitwise OR (`|`): Result is 1 when at least one operand bit is 1, else 0 if both operand bits are 0.
3. Bitwise XOR (`^`): Result is 1 when one, and only one operand bit is 1, else the result is 0. These three operators (`&, |, ^`) produce the same result irrespective of the order of operand bits.
4. Bitwise AND NOT (`&^`): Result is 1 when the first operand bit is 1, and the second operand bit is 0; else the result is 0. Note that the order of the operand bit affects the result. For the result to be 1, the first operand bit *must* be 1 and the second *must* be 0.

Here's code, [also on the Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/p4Ns8tRRn0), that demonstrates the behavior of bitwise operators:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`AND`)
    fmt.Printf("%b & %b results in %03b\n", 4, 5, 4&5)
    fmt.Printf("%b & %b results in %03b\n", 5, 4, 5&4)
    fmt.Println(`OR`)
    fmt.Printf("%b | %b results in %03b\n", 4, 5, 4|5)
    fmt.Printf("%b | %b results in %03b\n", 5, 4, 5|4)
    fmt.Println(`XOR`)
    fmt.Printf("%b ^ %b results in %03b\n", 4, 5, 4^5)
    fmt.Printf("%b ^ %b results in %03b\n", 5, 4, 5^4)
    fmt.Println(`AND NOT`)
    fmt.Printf("%b &^ %b results in %03b\n", 7, 5, 7&^5)
    fmt.Printf("%b &^ %b results in %03b\n", 5, 7, 5&^7)
}
```

The output generated by running the above code is:

```
AND
100 & 101 results in 100
101 & 100 results in 100
OR
100 | 101 results in 101
101 | 100 results in 101
XOR
100 ^ 101 results in 001
101 ^ 100 results in 001
AND NOT
111 &^ 101 results in 010
101 &^ 111 results in 000
```

And finally, `&^=` is a shorthand assignment operator. For example, `x = x &^ y` can be replaced by `x &^= y`

Answer (score 1):

The [spec says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) that they are the bit clear operators:

```
&^   bit clear (AND NOT)    integers
```

You would use them as part of a bit flag value.  You'd use `or` to turn on a bit, and `and not` to turn it off.